# Shall I set the Ethernet padding with all zero byte

Tags: padding, router, ethernet, rfc

I'm confused with RFC 894:

> The minimum length of the data field of a packet sent over an
>   Ethernet is 46 octets.  If necessary, the data field should be padded 
>   (with octets of zero) to meet the Ethernet minimum frame size.  This padding 
>   is not part of the IP packet and is not included in the total 
>   length field of the IP header.

it says if the data less than 46 octets,I should add a padded to reach 46 octets and set the filed as zero octets.
but to archive this, i have to give more steps, which means performance loss.
I've tried left it with junk data, and there seems nor problem.
Is that necessary to fill the pad with all zero bytes?

Comment: The text mentions 'If necessary' the data 'should' be padded. These are words which to me, mean optional. To me that means that this step is required to be compliant only and may have no effect on operation.

Comment: Well, I've set all the pad with zero octets, whatever. I don't want any routers or Server Drop my packet on the internet. But i thought This Pad is necessary and the